# Error while reading XML in a dictionary

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<APICollection><API name="myapiName" message="myAPIMessage" /></APICollection>
```

When I try to read this in a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> apiMap = new Dictionary<string,string>();    
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);    
apiMap = xdoc.Root.Elements()
              .ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("apiName"), a => (string)a.Attribute("apiMessage"));
```

everything works great. But, if I have multiple entries with the same key (name), I get a generic exception like this:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

I wonder what can I do to modify the error message to at least provide which key was present multiple times. Can anyone help, please?

Thanks,

Harit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd propose not to create the dictionary directly, but to first check for duplicate keys like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);    
var apiMap = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                 .Select(a => new
                     {
                         ApiName = (string)a.Attribute("apiName"),
                         ApiMessage = (string)a.Attribute("apiMessage")
                     });
var duplicateKeys = (from x in apiMap
                     group x by x.ApiName into g
                     select new { ApiName = g.Key, Cnt = g.Count() })
                     .Where(x => x.Cnt > 1)
                     .Select(x => x.ApiName);
if (duplicateKeys.Count() > 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The following keys are present more than once: " 
            + string.Join(", ", duplicateKeys));

Dictionary<string, string> apiMapDict = 
    apiMap.ToDictionary(a => a.ApiName, a => a.ApiMessage);
```

Please note that I've changed the code that there is a difference between the attribute names in your sample ("name", "message") and in the code sample ("apiName", "apiMessage").

Answer (score 0):

the `Attribute` method takes the attribute names, not values. Replace the values with the attribute names. Also use the `Value` property, to get the value of the attribute.

Even doing this though, your attribute values used as the key will need to be unique - as you are using a `Dictionary<T,T>`

```
Dictionary<string,string> apiMap = new Dictionary<string,string>();    
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);    
apiMap = xdoc.Root.Elements()
              .ToDictionary(a => a.Attribute("name").Value
                            , a => a.Attribute("message").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(path); 
var values = xmlDocument
             .Descendants("API")
             .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"))
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                           x => x.Select(p => (string)p.Attribute("message").ToList());
```

This will give you a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, keys are names and the values are the messages that belongs the Api name.If you just want Dictionary then change the code like this:

```
var values = xmlDocument
             .Descendants("API")
             .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"))
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                           x => (string)x.First().Attribute("message"));
```